# What does this do? `Find ... -type d|xargs chmod 770`

Tags: pipe, xargs

What does these two lines do?

```
find /backup/folder -type d|xargs chmod 770
find /backup/folder -type f|xargs chmod 660
```

I googled around, but can't figure out what `d|xargs` and `f|xargs` does.

Comment: Explained the long way around in the now existing answer, what you're missing is that | is a pipe connecting two different commands.  The find portion before the pipe creates a list then piped to xargs.  In short, the first find is looking for directories (-type d) and the second find is looking for plain files (-type f).

Comment: https://explainshell.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned `d|xargs` and `f|xargs` but none of these makes sense by itself. The first command may be written as:

```
{ find /backup/folder -type d ; } | { xargs chmod 770 ; }
```

So the question may be: what does `find … | xargs …` do? It takes what `find` outputs and makes it arguments of what is after `xargs`.

In the first command `find` finds all directories under `/backup/folder` (including `/backup/folder`. Then `xargs` executes:

```
chmod 770 <all_these_directories_here>
```

The effect is all these directories permissions are now `770` (unless you couldn't change them in the first place). This means full access for the owner, the group, no access for other users.

The second command tries to set `660` permissions to all files (due to `-type f`) under `/backup/folder`. This means read and write permission for the owner, the same for the group, no access for other users.

---

Note `chmod` has `-R` option that makes it recursive. However it's hardly useful when you need to set all the permissions at once, because you almost always need different permissions for directories than for files, like in this case.

Invoking `chmod -R 770 /backup/folder` sets all the files therein as executables (for their owner and the group) which is rarely what you want. On the other hand `chmod -R 660 /backup/folder` will prevent you from searching directories.

Running `find -type … | xargs chmod …` (or `find -type … -exec chmod … {} +`) with directories and (separately) files in mind is the way to go.

Comment: It would be good to mention that `find` and `xargs` should preferably be only used with `-print0` and `-0`, respectively, to make it more robust.

Comment: How do I find out what the `d` and the `f` means? I can't find any help or documentation for the find-command. 

And slhck - why is find more 'robust' with those flags? What difference does it make?

Comment: @Zeth Read the manpage: `man find`. Or [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html). About robustness: you want your shell commands to be robust against files that contain unusual characters. In this case, even whitespace is "unusual", as it may break some commands, especially those that rely upon parsing lists of files. For example, read FAQ entry number 1 here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls